# Contains method in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

I use this method to extract table name and field name from formula.

```
public List<string> ExtractFieldsFromFormula(string formula)
{
    List<string> formulas = new List<string>();
    formulas.AddRange(formula.Split(new char[] {'{', '}'}).Where(f=>!f.Contains("+") && !f.Contains("-")&&!f.Contains("/")&&!f.Contains("*")&& !f.Contains("(")&& !f.Contains(")") && f.Trim()!=String.Empty));
    return formulas;
}
```

my formula is like this:

> "{City.a}+5*(2/{City.b})"

and result of method is a list :

- City.a
- City.b

how can i write this code better than this?!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And there's always a place for a regular expression (especially when searching for a pattern in a string of characters ;-)).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"\{(?<expr>[a-zA-Z0-9.]+?)\}";
            string formula = @"{City.a}+5*(2/{City.b})";


            var matches = Regex.Matches(formula, pattern).OfType<Match>();
            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["expr"]);
            }
            // prints
            // City.a
            // City.b

            string splitPattern = @"\{(?<object>[a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\.(?<field>[a-zA-Z0-9]+?)\}";

            matches = Regex.Matches(formula, splitPattern).OfType<Match>();
            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Object: {0}   Field: {1}", match.Groups["object"], match.Groups["field"]);
            }

            // prints
            // Object: City   Field: a
            // Object: City   Field: b
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Named matches?!? You made my day.

Answer (score 3):

This should a) make it a bit more compact and b) be a bit faster.

```
    private static readonly char[] splitChars = new[] { '{', '}' };

    private static readonly char[] charsToExclude = new[] { '+', '-', '/', '*', '(', ')' };

    public static List<string> ExtractFieldsFromFormula(string formula)
    {
        var formulas = new List<string>();

        formulas.AddRange(formula.Split(splitChars).Where(f => (f.Trim().Length > 0) && (f.IndexOfAny(charsToExclude) == -1)));
        return formulas;
    }
```